# Shortest way of sorting and comparing two lists

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have two lists , one is of type String and another is of type Resp(a model class). I want to sort the Resp By comparing from first list like if string list contains: **“abc”,”iis”,”kjkk”** then the same order is maintained in Resp list .
The Resp list of type :

```
data class Resp(
    @SerializedName("firstname")
    val first: String,

    @SerializedName("number")
    val number: Int
})
```

So the sorting is to be done using Resp.first

What I am trying is:

```
resp.sortedWith(Comparator{ s1, s2 -> 
    s1.first.compareTo(staticlist.indexOf(s2.bUName))
})
```

But here the issue is I am not able to get the index of s1.first.

So please give any suggestions to work this out

Comment: I don't get the "I want to sort the Resp By comparing from first list like if string list contains ...".
1. string list contains: “abc”,”iis”,”kjkk” >> is this on the first list or the second list on Resp class?
2. Assume that was on the first list. You want to sort List of Resp based on the first list. Then which one is true: the string on each of the Resp object containing one of the string on the first list, or vice versa?
3. You sure "containing"? Because I see it is more make sense if you sort it based on complete similarity, or at least by prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution would be to just rebuild the list of Resp elements from the order you gathered by iterating `strList`. In case there is no counterpart in the `respList` it will not be part of the result list.

```
val strList = listOf("abc", "iis", "kjkk") // desired order
val respList = listOf(Resp("iis"), Resp("kjkk"), Resp("abc")) // unsorted

val result = strList.flatMap { str -> 
    respList.filter { 
        it.first == str
    }
}
```

Result:

> [Resp(first=abc), Resp(first=iis), Resp(first=kjkk)]

Comment: what if the Resp contains duplicate entries also?

Comment: @CosmicDev Then I would use .filter instead of .firstOrNull. Good point. Maybe it's a good idea to do that in the first place. I edited the answer.

Comment: @CosmicDev "Kotlin in Action" (book), Kotlin Koans: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/koans.html and browsing through this: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer this by java. I assume the first list is the standard to consider the order of the list of Resp objects.
First, we need to map that first list into a map of string (as a key) and Integer (as an order value). And of course, since this is the standard for order, the value of each string must be unique:

```
List<String> orderRaw = new LinkedList<>();
List<Resp> resps = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Integer> order = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < orderRaw.size(); i++) {
  String s = orderRaw.get(i);
  order.put(s, i);
}
```

Then, you can sort the list of Resp objects like this:

```
List<Resp> resps = new ArrayList<>();
resps.sort((o1, o2) -> {
  final Integer i1 = order.get(o1);
  final Integer i2 = order.get(o2);
  if (Objects.equals(i1, i2)) {    //either both null or have the same index
    return 0;
  } else if (i1 == null) {   //only i1 is null
    return -1;
  } else if (i2 == null) {   //only i2 is null
    return 1;
  } else {
    return i1 - i2;
  }
});
```

Hope it gives you the idea.